# Using regex to capture text in parenthesis if they exist

Tags: python, regex

Right now I am working on a python script to parse the My Clippings file generated by kindles when someone highlights, takes a note, or bookmarks. I am using regex to collect the data from the file, then I plan on storing it in a sqlite database. Right now though, I am having trouble matching the line that contains the title of the book and possibly an author.

There are three possibilities for this line. They can be in the format:

```
Title (Last, First)
Title (Author)
Title
```

What I want is for the regex to capture the title, and whatever is in the ending parenthesis if it exists, otherwise capture a blank string. So for example, I want the regex here to give me the results:

```
('Title', 'Last, First')
('Title', 'Author')
('Title', '')
```

Right now I managed to do a regex that captures the parenthesis, but not the titles without authors. Here is what I have now:

```
(.+) (?:\((.+)\)(?:\n|\Z))*
```

The only issue is that it requires that the line ends with an author, and if I give it an option to accept a blank string, it finds that the entire line is the title without an author. i.e.

```
('Title (Last, First)', '')
('Title (Author)', '')
('Title', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to match line by line, you can use this regex:

```
^(.+?)(?: \((.+)\))?$
```

I added the start of line anchor and end of line anchor, then put the space in the first non-capturing group, so that the title without any other details can be captured. I changed the `*` operator to `?`, since I don't think you'll have more than one pair of brackets. Change if you think you do have more.

I removed the second non capturing group as the end of line anchor will ensure it's the end of the line.

Demo [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/hA5hQ7).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version, which is very similar to Jerry's, but perhaps a little safer:

```
(\w+?)(?:\s?\(([\w,\s]*)\))?$
```

This covers a few more cases such as indentation, missing a space before the brackets, and empty brackets.

Here's a demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/8C1pireOwV

Comment: I don't think you need to make the starting \w+? non greedy in this case. It just adds needless backtracking. Other than that I like the flexibility of this answer.

Comment: Hmm, the regex in your answer differs from the one in your demo. (\w+?)(?:\s?\(([\w,\s]*)\))?$

Comment: Ah yes, oops - I'd just changed a "+" to a "*", to account for empty brackets.
Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

With a file like:

```
Title (Last, First)
Title (Author)
Title 
Title ()
    Title ()
The Title (Bob, Jones)
```

The following:

```
import re
matches = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches.append(re.match(r'^\s*([\w\s]+) \(?(.*?)\)?$',line).groups())

for m in matches:
    print m
('Title', 'Last, First')
('Title', 'Author')
('Title', '')
('Title', '')
('Title', '')
('The Title', 'Bob, Jones')
>>>
```

Will produce your desired result.